# Android Matrix.postScale(factorA,factorB) How does it work?

Tags: android, post, matrix, scale

We are talking about this function [postScale(float,float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postScale%28float,%20float%29)
The official documentation states that its result is this: M' = S(sx, sy) * M

I'd like to know how this function works internally:

- what is its scaling pivot point
- what is the form of the matrix S(sx, sy)

I need to better understand its internal working in order to keep track of a point inside my `ImageView` component. I track this point manually, but after I apply a `postScale` to my `Matrix` object, I can't figure out what happened to it.

Any help and tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need that knowledge: use one of Matrix.mapPoints method

Comment: It is a useful tip, but I cannot use this method. I need to know the inner workings of the Matrix.postScale in order to emulate it's results. Because I can't apply it to this particular Matrix. I only need to apply it to my point, which I keep on it's own stored.

Comment: i dont understand, why cannot you use mapPoins? you have a Matrix that you postSvale so why you cannot use it?

Comment: I'll give a better clarification of the situation. I have image A that is my background, and Image B which is on top of my background. When I scale A I need to keep B in the same point relative to A. This means that if my original top-left angle of B is at (200,300) in A, after I scale A by a factor of 1,5, my A point will be (300,450). This is where I need B's top-left angle to be. To do this, a translation of B image is required. I need B to have the same dimension as before.

Comment: and this is what mapPoints exactly makes